# mod_proxy with apache tomcat, how do I set it up?

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, tomcat6

I have my app that serves on localhost:8080. I want to configure things so that it just servers on localhost:80 (or localhost without the port specified). I was told to follow [these instructions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html).

My apache-tomcat that I downloaded is located at /home/myusername/tools/appname/apache-tomcat-6.0.33

I can't find an httpd.conf file in that dir... so I can't make the changes that the above article mentions. I am not sure what to do. I am new to apache/tomcat. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions are for *apache*, which is different from apache's *tomcat*. What you have (the 6.0.33 thing) is apache's *tomcat*, which hosts/runs webapps but isn't typically used as a general webserver. You need to download and install apache, then you'll be able to follow those instructions.

You can download the apache webserver here: http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Or if you are using an OS with a package manager, use your OS'es package manager instead.

Typically, the httpd.conf file should be at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (or `/etc/apache/httpd.conf`).